# Absolute import in conda env

Tags: python, conda

I met with a problem with absolute import when using conda env. Here is the structure of my project.

- project/

  - package_1/

    - __init__.py
    - file_1.py
    - subpackage_1/

      - run.py

In `package_1.subpackage_1.run.py` there is an absolute import `import package_1.file_1`. However, when I ran `python package_1/subpackage_1/run.py` in `package` folder, I got an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_1'`. I tried to print `sys.path`. `project.package_1.subpackage_1` is in `sys.path`, but the folder from where I ran the command, `project` is not. I tried to add `project` in `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`, but it doesn't work in conda env. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

You can accomplish what you want with relative imports, or with absolute imports if you restructure your project. Modifying your `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` should not be your go-to solution. If you really want global availability, you could install your local package with `conda`.

### Option 1: [Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

If you want to be able to run a file inside a sub-module directly (i.e. `python package_1/subpackage_1/run.py`) then you should consider using **relative imports**.

**Example:**

```
project/
  package_1/
    __init__.py
    file_1.py
    subpackage_1/
      __init__.py
      run.py
```

```py
# run.py

import ..file_1
```

### Option 2: Absolute Imports

If you want to use **absolute imports**, then your entry point (the script that you run) should be in the top level (`package_1`) instead of inside a sub-package.

**Example:**

```
project/
  package_1/
    __init__.py
    run.py
    file_1.py
    subpackage_1/
      __init__.py
      stuff.py
```

```py
# run.py

import package_1.subpackage_1.stuff

stuff.run()

# stuff.py

import package_1.file_1
```

### Option 3: Installing your local package with `conda`

Once you [configure your package correctly](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#) you should be able to simply run

```
conda install .
```

Which will install your local package as if it were a published package. This is likely overkill for your needs.

### Why not modify `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`?

If you rely on having your local package path on `PYTHONPATH`, you every time you move the project or copy it onto a new computer.

Appending entries to `sys.path` in code often accomplishes a similar effect to what you can do with relative imports, but later import statements lose semantics.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do this is to add the directory to your `sys.path` with this code at the top of `run.py`

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'package_1'))
```

And then change the line in run.py

```
import package_1.file_1
```

to

```
import file_1
```

Now python can import `file1` directly since its directory is on the path.

Comment: This solution, while functional, is no longer an absolute import like the OP requested.

Comment: @Aposhian - the last lines of the OP's question are `I tried to add project in PATH or PYTHONPATH, but it doesn't work in conda env. Does anyone know how to fix this?`  - This solution fixes this issue. I do not see where the OP specifies that the solution needs to be an absolute import.

Comment: Fair. However, I understood (perhaps incorrectly) that the OP wanted to do absolute imports and thought that adding the package to the PYTHONPATH would solve that problem. Absolute imports are preferred in the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: @Aposhian - In that case. I don't think the downvote is justified.

Comment: Fair. However, I am not allowed to retract my vote until an edit is made, so I have submitted one.